# Unable to close fullscreen menu after clicking on Navlink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu, react-router, react-hooks

**Problem**

Full screen menu doesn't want to be closed when I click on a link. This problem occurs with the NavLink element if I use html tag a and everything works as it should.

Here I have a function that should enable me to shut down when I press one of the links. I mentioned earlier its works only for a href tag.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const useOnClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event) => {
      if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }
      handler(event);
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
    };
  }, [ref, handler]);
};
```

Here is the main menu component

```
const MobileMenu = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef();

  useOnClickOutside(ref, () => setOpen(false));

  return (
    <MobileMenuWrapper ref={ref}>
      <BurgerIcon open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <MobileMenuList open={open} setOpen={setOpen}>
        <MenuLinks />
      </MobileMenuList>
    </MobileMenuWrapper>
  );
};
```

And the links component

```
const MenuLinks = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/"> Home</NavLink>
        </li>

        <li>
          <NavLink to="/albums">Albums</NavLink>
        </li>

        <li>
          <NavLink to="/addAlbum">Add Album</NavLink>
        </li>

        <li>
          <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
        </li>

        <li>
          <NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hey can you share some screenshots?

Comment: @VikrantBhat i record video shwoing this problem

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ouTCBP_bCaoRpzKExfpYpdBuiG3KwtDu/view

Comment: I think it`s because a href reloads sites and lose state , NavLink or Link doesnt reload site,but i dont know how i can helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of serching bug i solve it

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const ref = useRef();
  // on link click change open to false
  useOutsideClick(ref, () => {
    if (open) setOpen(false);
  });

  return (
    <MobileMenuWrapper ref={ref}>
      <BurgerIcon open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <MobileMenuList open={open} setOpen={setOpen}>
        <MenuLinks />
      </MobileMenuList>
    </MobileMenuWrapper>
  );
```

and hook

```
export const useOutsideClick = (ref, callback) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (ref.current && ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      callback();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  });
};
```